# Codeigniter gmap adding markers in view rather than controller

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, codeigniter-2

Trying to list a bunch of addresses with gmap.

Code in controller has this initialization steps:

```
$this->load->library('GMap');
$this->gmap->GoogleMapAPI();
$this->gmap->setMapType('map');
```

Was using the addMarkerByAddress in the same function as below and it was working:

```
$this->gmap->addMarkerByAddress($address,$ordername, $ordertitle, $tooltip, $icon_leaf);
```

When I try the same code in the view file it fails.  I understand how to pass data to the views for display purposes (using the `$data[]` variable) but how do I get the gmap instance from the main file so it can be referenced in the view?

Comment: Could you use `$data['gmap'] = $this->gmap;`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the object through

```
$data["gmap"] -> $this->gmap
```

Or you can create a Helper with the function/s you need, when you load the helper in the controller, you can access it without problem in the view.

Your view must not access controller's methods/variables/objects.